# Can functions return sets?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The definition of a function is ([link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/FunctionDefn.aspx)):

> A function is a relation for which each value from the set the first
>   components of the ordered pairs is associated with exactly **one value**
>   from the set of second components of the ordered pair.

Cantor's theorem states that:

> Given any set $A$, there does not exist a function $f:A \rightarrow
>  \mathcal{P}(A)$ that is onto.

So the codomain of $f$ is power set of $A$. Yes, the theorem tells there is no such function but is it even possible in the first place to define a function which returns (or points) a set? If so, can you give an example?

Comment: $a\mapsto\{a\}$ is an example.

Comment: Each set in the image of $f$ is one value, regardless of the number of elements in that set. So you could define, say, $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ by $f(n):=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Then each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ has a unique value, namely the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. It's not as if all values of $f(n)$ are $1$, $2$ all the way up to $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set is one value. One set. Just like a box of marbles is one box. This has nothing to do with how many elements the set can contain. So, yes, it is possible to define a function which returns sets:

Let $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$. Define $f(1)=\{1,2\}$ and $f(2)=\{1\}$.

Or $Y'=\{\Bbb R,\Bbb Q\}$ and $g(1)=\Bbb Q$, $g(2)=\Bbb R$.

In fact, in maths, *everything* is a set.

Comment: That last statement is...problematic, for reasons which are far beyond the scope of a basic course. (For the initiated: while there is a formalism in set theory, Godel's theorems tell us that this formalism can't encompass everything there is to say about number theory.)

Comment: Well, let's say then that every number is a set :)

Answer (score 2):

The counter question should be, why not? One fun example:

$f: \Bbb Z^+ \to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z^+) $ by 
$f(n) = \{1,...,n\} $.

Answer (score 1):

I think that we owe the OP with the following explanation: The Cantor theorem claims that there is no one to one map between a set and the set of all subsets of it. This does not mean that one cannot create set valued functions. (See the other answers.)